# Export Canvas extent inside QGIS at a 1m resolution GeoTIFF format

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, imagery, global-mapper

I am working with the "XYZ Tiles Google Earth" inside QGIS and I have an area of interest that is roughly a 2 nautical mile radius that I would like to export as a GeoTIFF with a 1m resolution to use as a reference in another program. Currently in order to get it to the resolution I desire I have to zoom in to the scale I want and then export the canvas extent. The problem with doing it this way is that I would have to somehow keep track of where I am at and end up with a lot of small exports that I would have to stitch together later on. I was hoping if someone knew of a method in which I could export the entire area of interest I have at 1 meter resolution size scale. Or if anyone knows of an entire different method?

Comment: Just right click the layer in the TOC and select `Export` then `Save As` options. You can then set extent, resolution and format. Have a look at: https://www.geodose.com/2020/08/how-to-save-google-map-satellite-imagery-qgis.html